# Folland theorem 6.13

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I read theorem 6.13 out of Folland’s book. I was wondering what goes wrong if you take q = infty. Is there a nice counterexample?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=[0,1]$ with measure $\delta_0+\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, while $\delta_0((0,1])=0,\delta_0(\{0\})=\infty$.

Let $g$ be the indicator function of $\{0\}$: $\|g\|_{\infty}=1$.

Let $f \in L^1(X)$: then $f(0)=0$, thus $fg=0$. Hence $\|\phi_g\|=0 < \|g\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think the condition $\| f \|_p =1$ is not met, since f = 0, right?

Comment: No, $f$ is not zero! $f$ just has to vanish at zero, but $f$ could be, for instance, the indicator function of the interval $(0,1]$ (see the definition of the measure).

Comment: ah thank you very much!